# Unable to play QMediaPlayer from a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qmediaplayer

I am wondering why the QMediaPlayer not playing from another thread, but it starts play while the caller thread stopped.

For example:

Thread `A` call (calling is done by signals-slot) to thread `B` start to play MP3, but thread `A` continues his job, but thread `B` although receiving the play command, but still not playing, but when I stop the thread `A`, then the player starts playing. So thread A and B cannot be run at the same time.

Why it is like this, there is no any relation between these two threads, just a simple `signal` to thread `B` to start playing.

Code: Header

```
class Alarm : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Alarm();
    ~Alarm();

signals:
    void play();
    void stop();

private:
    QMediaPlayer *player;
    QThread alarmThread;
};
```

.cpp

```
Alarm::Alarm() : QObject()
{
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/media/alarm_music.mp3"));
    player->setVolume(80);
    connect(this, &Alarm::play, this, [this]() {
        if(player->state() == QMediaPlayer::PlayingState) {
            return;
        }
        player->play();
    });
    connect(this, &Alarm::stop, player, &QMediaPlayer::stop);

    moveToThread(&alarmThread);
    alarmThread.start();
}

Alarm::~Alarm()
{
    alarmThread.quit();
    alarmThread.wait();
    delete player;
}
```

Comment: Post a minimal but complete code example.

Comment: @Navie I have already detailed clearly if you understand, you know what can be the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Navie It does not belong to code, there is no wrong with the code, it belongs to API, the code it is working OK, playing sounds, but the problem is it is not playing while trying to call the play signal from another thread.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Do you use any widget next to the QMediaPlayer?

Comment: @eyllanesc No, I just want to play a 5sec MP3, it is working well, the problem happens when the worker thread signals to the Player thread to play Mp3, and the worker thread continues its job, but the Mp3 not playing, and when I pause/stop the worker thread, then the player thread starts playing.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have printed the thread id of caller and reciever, they are all in the different threads, and I used the signal slot to call between threads.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Why do you use a thread to play if QMediaPlayer is GUI friendly? I see it unnecessary

Comment: @BahramdunAdil 
I think that QMediaPlayer can only run on the main thread

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried both, with and without thread all not working, at the first time I did use thread, it was not working, I thing maybe it needs to be run in a different threads, but also not working

Comment: @BahramdunAdil 
I think you have implemented it incorrectly, so I would ask you for a [mcve], but I see that you do not want to do it, so I can not tell you anything else. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc the magic part is why it starts plying when the caller thread pause or stopped?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil as I told you if you do not provide a [mcve] unfortunately I can not help you, it has happened to me many times that the asker says that he has implemented it correctly and at the end there is always an error, if there is no code I will not be able to continue helping you :)

Comment: @eyllanesc I posted the code, but I don't know why it was not successfully posted, only the question remains, the code part was disappeared.

Comment: @eyllanesc I will try to post it again.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil maybe it is a very extensive code, take the necessary time and provide a [mcve], understand that they are not pieces of code, but must be complete, in that missing part can be the error. :)

Comment: Are you using `QueuedConnection`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil 
as I see by your code I do not see the need for the thread, the threads in a GUI are used so that blocking tasks (that consume a lot of time) do not block the GUI, and in your case it is not necessary. Could you explain the need?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes I have tested this in UI thread, it was working. The reason which I put the player in the separate threads was that I think QMediaPlayer will block the UI until the media file finishes as Java does. So it seems that there is no need for this?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil No, just Qt offers classes that are GUI-friendly. and this is demonstrated by the use of signals to indicate the state.

Comment: @eyllanesc OK I see now, and problem has been solved. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Recommendation: If the class consumes a lot of time, move it to a thread, if it does not do it let the eventloop handle it and if you want to inform yourself about the process, use the signals. in your case, measure the time in the method play() or setMedia() or setVolume() and check if it consumes a lot of time.

Comment: @eyllanesc Hmmmm I will do test for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you instantiating `QMediaPlayer` without setting its parent, it continues to "live" in the thread where the `Alarm` object was constructed. If that thread has no event loop, `QMediaPlayer` will not function properly.

Also, it's unsafe to call `start`/`stop` from a thread that `QMediaPlayer` is not bound to.

Also, it is legit to construct a `QObject` by value; you don't have to use `new` to instantiate every single `QObject`.